# Replace IN clause with JOIN in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have read that JOIN is preferred over IN clause, so I am trying get rid of IN from my query

```
SELECT MSG.MSG_ID
FROM F1_MSG_OUT MSG
WHERE MSG.MSG_ID  IN (
  SELECT MSG_ID
  FROM F1_MSG_OUT_ID MSGID2
  WHERE MSGID2.MSG_ID = MSG.MSG_ID
  AND TRIM(MSGID2._ID_TYPE_FLG) = :F6
  AND TRIM(MSGID2._ID_VALUE)   = :F3
  )
AND MSG.MSG_ID IN (
  SELECT MSG_ID
  FROM F1_MSG_OUT_ID MSGID3
  WHERE MSGID3.MSG_ID = MSG.MSG_ID
  AND TRIM(MSGID3._ID_TYPE_FLG) = :F5
  AND TRIM(MSGID3._ID_VALUE) = :F4
  )
```

Comment: Note that a JOIN instead of IN might produce duplicated rows - depending on the table data.

Comment: Where did you read that? They are different in terms of the result and Oracle's optimizer is smart enough to decide what to use. In general, `in` do the same as `join`, but it is named as `hash join semi` in the query plan. [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=257de4df2c2930a3606d886b9782a5ef), but it depends. So no such a rule "prefer join over in". Also `in` predicate allows optimization with `precompute_subquery` hint for example, which can change the query plan dramatically compared to join

Comment: `EXISTS` is probably a better option than `JOIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like

```
select msg.msg_id
from f1_msg_out msg join f1_msg_out_id msgid2 on msgid2.msg_id = msg.msg_id
                    join f1_msg_out_id msgid3 on msgid3.msg_id = msg.msg_id
where trim(msgid2._id_type_flg) = :f6
  and trim(msgid2._id_value)    = :f3
  and trim(msgid3._id_type_flg) = :f5
  and trim(msgid3._id_value)    = :f4;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what i have been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You already have answer for joining. You can also use `exists` in place of `in` line below

```
SELECT MSG.MSG_ID
FROM F1_MSG_OUT MSG
WHERE exists  (
  SELECT 1
  FROM F1_MSG_OUT_ID MSGID2
  WHERE MSGID2.MSG_ID = MSG.MSG_ID
  AND TRIM(MSGID2._ID_TYPE_FLG) = :F6
  AND TRIM(MSGID2._ID_VALUE)   = :F3
  )
AND exists IN (
  SELECT 1
  FROM F1_MSG_OUT_ID MSGID3
  WHERE MSGID3.MSG_ID = MSG.MSG_ID
  AND TRIM(MSGID3._ID_TYPE_FLG) = :F5
  AND TRIM(MSGID3._ID_VALUE) = :F4
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT MSG.MSG_ID
FROM F1_MSG_OUT MSG
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT MSGID2.MSG_ID
                FROM F1_MSG_OUT_ID MSGID2
                WHERE MSGID2.MSG_ID = MSG.MSG_ID
                AND TRIM(MSGID2._ID_TYPE_FLG) = :F6
                AND TRIM(MSGID2._ID_VALUE)   = :F3
)
AND EXISTS (        SELECT MSGID3.MSG_ID
                    FROM F1_MSG_OUT_ID MSGID3
                    WHERE MSGID3.MSG_ID = MSG.MSG_ID
                    AND TRIM(MSGID3._ID_TYPE_FLG) = :F5
                    AND TRIM(MSGID3._ID_VALUE) = :F4
)
```